# How to programatically send messages to IRC channel

Tags: php, bots, irc

Does anyone know how to programatically:

- Send messages to an specific IRC (Internet Relay Chat) channel ? or
- Send a message to all users in a channel ? or
- Send an automatic message as a reply ?

I'm accustomed to use PHP, but doesn't really matter the language.

Thank you !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically need to:

1. Connect to the server.
2. Join the channel.
3. Send the message to the channel.

---

### Connecting

You need to open a connection to the IRC server. It's usually done with the `fsockopen()` function.

The server expects two commands, `NICK` and `USER`. Note that the sever expects `\r\n` as a line-ending (if you don't send it, the server won't accept your commands).

After those two commands are sent, the server will send you a ping.

```
:irc.servername.com PING :RANDOM-STRING
```

You must reply it with `PONG :RANDOM-STRING` (Same string). The server will periodically send those if you are not active. If you fail to reply, the server will assume you died, and close the connection.

### Joining the channel

After connection phase is over (You can tell it because you'll get a 001 command from the server when you do), you join the channel. Send the following command:

```
JOIN #channel-name
```

The server will join you to the channel, send you the TOPIC and the NAMES list. Once that's over, you've joined the channel.

### Sending the message

If all of the above went correctly, all you need is

```
PRIVMSG #channel-name :YOUR MESSAGE HERE
```

Anything after the colon is the message.

---

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thx, I know how to create the connection, but how I can send this IRC specific commands to this connection ?

Comment: Really useful answer. Ty !! Just to complete:
http://www.d3scene.com/forum/operating-systems/16929-creating-irc-bot-php.html and http://php.net/manual/es/function.fsockopen.php and http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php

Comment: Found http://www.wildphp.com/simple-irc-bot and https://github.com/phergie/phergie-irc-generator Too !! :D

Comment: `fwrite()` to the connection handler usually does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the RFC for IRC so you can build your own client.

See http://www.irchelp.org/protocol/rfc/